# Define class method property with ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

In ES5 syntax, a class `Foo` with a method `bar` having a property `flag` can be defined like:

```js
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.bar = function() { console.log('bar invoked'); };
Foo.prototype.bar.flag = true;
```

I could mix up ES5 and ES6 syntax and do:

```js
class Foo {
  bar() {
    console.log('bar invoked');
  };
};
Foo.prototype.bar.flag = true;
```

Or using just ES6 syntax do:

```js
class Foo {
  bar() {
    this.bar.flag = true;
    console.log('bar invoked');
  };
};
```

If I have to choose I'd go for second option but I dislike the redundancy in including the name of the method within it's definition. Is there a better way?

Comment: Attaching properties to functions is normally quite rare. Attaching them to *methods* it's rarer still. In fact, this might be the first time I've seen this. Are you sure you actually *need* classes? Having classes where the *methods* also carry properties [smells wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Are you sure this is [the true solution to a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for your comment. This is not a class I'm writing from scratch. I can design a better solution using an object for each of the methods in the class, but I already have an ES5 class defined like this and would like to migrate it into ES6 syntax. The refactor may come later :)

Comment: I'd suggest going with solution 2, in that case. It's the cleanest and closest to your original.

Comment: Also note that the third option does not have the same outcome as the other two because it only sets the flag when `obj.bar()` is actually called.  The others set the flag at initialization time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no declarative way to create a property on a method in JavaScript *(it's quite a rare thing to do)*, so if you want to do that, you have to do it after-the-fact as in your second example. (Or your third, but that's repeated every time `bar` is called so it's a bit misleading and/or possibly not that useful.)

Answer (score 3):

If you can go beyond ES2015 and do not afraid to use experimental things you could play with decorators. [Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oAEBm4Dm60ARmAE4AUAlCoRsPAHYTwgCmAdCPHuQOQmloASwYA3eAGtWAE16UA3IQC-ilalTYArg2AAXIY2i4wPXWTytd1NBjOkLu9tNYRgpIQAdd8Uu1FgQTQ5jPGgAXmhdUiDFDFJLTVIGSPNLVXVUeiZdI0Rw6AZWAHc4RCp1LOY2Tm5ybER2AXYQyiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.11.6&externalPlugins=).

```
class Foo {
  @flag
  bar() {
    console.log('bar invoked');
  };
};

function flag(target) {
  target.descriptor.value.flag = true;
  return target;
}


const foo = new Foo()

console.log(foo.bar.flag)
```

Comment: ***Very*** good point! Decorators have changed repeatedly and will change again, but one of these days, they'll make it through the process... :-) (Whether you'll be able to do this with the final result remains to be seen, but still, very good point.)

Comment: Yep, the proposal seems far from stable. But current iteration looks promising. At least they made it to stage 2. :)

Comment: Oh, all the previous iterations of the proposal also made it to Stage 2 and one of them briefly made it to Stage 3 before implementers said, basically, "we can't make this perform" and it went back to Stage 2. (For clarity: I'm not giving the people behind the proposal a hard time here, and I have a **huge** amount of respect for Dan Ehrenberg, whom I've worked with [in a very minor way] on decorators and others and who helped me with Chapter 1 of my new book. It's just been a really rocky road.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to reference the function being called using strict mode (remember that using classes makes strict mode automatic).

If you would ever want to do that, using ES5 "classes":

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
  console.log('bar invoked');
  arguments.callee.flag = true;
};
```

Remember that `arguments.callee` is disabled in strict mode.